# How do you get to the hidden star in Boulder Bowl Galaxy

Tags: super-mario-galaxy-2

I've been trying to collect as many stars as I can before moving onto the next world in Super Mario Galaxy 2. I'm up to World 4, but in Boulder Bowl Galaxy on World 2 there is a hidden star that is still eluding me.

What actions do I need to do to locate this star? If its availability is caused by an in game event what do I need to do to trigger the in game event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a star you can only earn after getting a message at the Mailtoad from one of the robots with the gear heads. After that you'll be able to meet him in the galaxy, he'll want you to lure a Gooma over to him. So, I guess keep playing and come back later.

Comment: It could be coincidence, but I got the message after collecting the first star in Chompworks Galaxy in World 4

Comment: @SteveBosman The first star of Chompworks is indeed the requirement for this message (from my experience, and as noted in the Japanese-language Shogakukan guidebook).

Answer (score 0):

After you get the letter from the Golden Gearmo, you have to go the planet with the boulders and Chomps, break the rock spikes by rolling into them. A Goomba will come of one. Lead it to the Golden Gearmo. He will thank you with a Power Star.